# Moving a window across an image

Tags: image, window, move, mask

I'm a bit confused on how a `window/mask` moves across an image. I know we start from the top left of the image, but how does the window continue moving especially that part of the window will exceed the dimensions of the image. I'm not asking for programming here, but would just kindly ask for an illustration on a window moving (i.e; 3x3) across an image. You can also refer me to some source if it is easier.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [resource](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/).

It is pretty exhaustive and provides comprehensive stuff about how to do the masking across an `image`. I hope this helps.